# Use of elapsed execution time as a variable input

Tags: encryption, factoring, complexity

Given that, with a significant number of decimals, it may be difficult to predict elapsed execution time of a piece of code, despite having knowledge of exact hardware and software specifications; is there any algorithm which uses the elapsed execution time of the encryption algorithm itself in order to feed mathematical complexity back into itself?

(I'm not suggesting this would be a good idea)

Comment: The only somewhat related idea is that (I think) good (OS?) CSPRNGs use some process scheduling infos (the actual "non-determinism" in programm timing) as entropy source, I don't know to what extent and how effective it is though.